# Fortran Compiling Errors

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile some Fortran code and I get the following errors,

```
WRITE(1,FMT='(A,I)') ' ncoefs= ',NFOUR  
                1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
```

and

```
WRITE(1,FMT='(A,100(F4.1,","))') ' spabnd= ',(SPABND(I),I=1,NLYR+1
                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

The weird thing about this second error is that in the actual code I have a bracket on the end of this expression, i.e., `(SPABND(I),I=1,NLYR+1)` is what it looks like.

Comment: I would recommend to post it as two separate problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is self-explaining, use `I0` or some positive number to set the field width. That is the number of characters that will be used to write the variable. Width `0` means the minimum number necessary to fit the value will be used. The `A` descriptor can be left as it is. In Fortran 2008 `g0` also works.

In the other case it seems that you exceeded the maximum line length. It is `72` characters in fixed-form and `132` characters in free-form. Try to split the line and use proper line continuation according to the source form.

Comment: Thanks - now, however, it says "Zero width in format descriptor in format string" when I replaced A and I with A0 and I0.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you must use `a` with positive number or without it (or `g0`). Why you accept answer that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The second code fragment can be written more concisely as

```
WRITE(1,FMT='(A,100(F4.1,","))') ' spabnd= ',SPABND(1:NLYR+1)
```

or

```
WRITE(1,FMT='(A,100(F4.1,","))') ' spabnd= ',SPABND(:NLYR+1)
```

if the lower bound or array SPABND is 1, as is usually the case in Fortran. The problem with your code likely has to do with line length, as Vladimir F wrote, but using more concise idioms is one way to avoid such errors.